# Regex for new line after last match

Tags: regex, mediawiki-api

I am using a program called [AutoWikiBrowser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:AutoWikiBrowser) to do some mass editing on a wiki. It is basically a search-and-replace using regular expressions. I want to replace the following text:

```
{{Infobox Book/List/Header|Second bookcase}}
{{:Book title 1|List}}
{{:Book title 2|List}}
{{:Book title 3|List}}
```

by the following text:

```
{{BookList|type=List/Sorted|caption=Second bookcase
 |Book title 1
 |Book title 2
 |Book title 3
}}
```

I have successfully come up with the following regex to replace the first line, find:

```
\{\{Infobox Book/List/Header\|(.*?)}}
```

and replace:

```
{{BookList|type=List/Sorted|caption=$1
```

and one or more of the next lines are found with:

```
\{\{:(.*?)\|List}}
```

and replaced with:

```
 |$1
```

However, after this last search-and-replace has happened, I want to add those two closing curly brackets on a new line. I am having trouble finding a way to implement this, because on forehand I cannot know how much book title rows there will be. Does somebody know a smart trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply **add** a new regex to replace the whole book list thing without the brackets to one with brackets:

```
{{BookList\|type=List\/Sorted\|caption=[^\n]+\n( \|[^\n]+\n)+
```

to

```
$0}}
```

Obviously, this needs to be tested and adapted against the numerous Wiki false positive that could occur since the data is rarely consistant there.

[You can see it here on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iO9uP3/2)

Comment: Note that AWB might need you to escape \ character with a second \ :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @brclz. I think your idea is on the right track, but it seems only the last captured group is remembered. When I search for: (\{\{:(.*?)\|List}}\s)+ to replace by:  |$2\n}} and test this against the following input: {{:Book title 1|List}}
{{:Book title 2|List}}
{{:Book title 3|List}}
{{:Book title 4|List}}
{{:Book title 5|List}} I get  |Book title 5

}}

Comment: Hello @Benjamin! Sorry my answer was super wrong, I just edited it and this should fit your needs.

Comment: Hey @brclz, thanks for your edited answer! I think it works, I will test a bit today and accept if it really works. Thanks!

Comment: Perfect. Feel free to tell me if something is wrong ;-)